# QuickBooks Enterprise 2016 using QBFC12 ICustomerMod ShipAddress causes huge performance hit

Tags: quickbooks, enterprise, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

I am using QBFC12 to modify a customer in a QuickBooks Enterprise 2016 company file.  I restored this client's company file from a backup, upgraded it to 2016 and have done a Rebuild Data on this file.  An ICustomerMod request without the ShipAddress takes about one second.  The otherwise identical ICustomerMod request with a ShipAddress takes about two minutes and 50 seconds which is very poor performance.  I have repeated these results multiple times.  This client must have the ShipAddress sent to their QB company file.  How do I improve this performance for our client?  Thanks.

Edit: I tried it with QBFC13 too, same results.  We have other clients experiencing the same issue.

```
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError">
<CustomerModRq requestID = "0">
<CustomerMod>
<ListID>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</ListID>
<EditSequence>1464263853</EditSequence>
<CompanyName>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</CompanyName>
<Salutation/>
<FirstName/>
<MiddleName/>
<LastName/>
<BillAddress>
<Addr1>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</Addr1>
<Addr2>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</Addr2>
<Addr3/>
<Addr4/>
<City>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</City>
<State>FL</State>
<PostalCode>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</PostalCode>
</BillAddress>
<ShipAddress>
<Addr1>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</Addr1>
<Addr2>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</Addr2>
<Addr3/>
<Addr4/>
<City>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</City>
<State>FL</State>
<PostalCode>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</PostalCode>
</ShipAddress>
<Phone>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</Phone>
<AltPhone/>
<Fax>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</Fax>
<Email/>
<Contact/>
<AltContact/>
<CustomerTypeRef>
<FullName>OMITTED FOR PRIVACY</FullName>
</CustomerTypeRef>
<TermsRef>
<FullName>Net 30</FullName>
</TermsRef>
<SalesRepRef>
<FullName/>
</SalesRepRef>
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
<FullName/>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
<ItemSalesTaxRef>
<FullName/>
</ItemSalesTaxRef>
<ResaleNumber/>
<AccountNumber/>
<CreditLimit/>
<JobDesc/>
<JobTypeRef>
<FullName/>
</JobTypeRef>
<PriceLevelRef>
<FullName/>
</PriceLevelRef>
</CustomerMod>
</CustomerModRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The request that works promptly is identical except the ShipAddress node is omitted and the EditSequence is different, obviously.

Here is an interesting observation.  The same request with the ShipAddress responds promptly when the ShipAddress is being modified.  The slow ICustomerMod is when the customer did not yet have a ShipAddress.

Edit: Alas.  I tried adding the ShipAddress to the ICustomerAdd request and that only shifted the slow response to there instead of the ICustomerMod request.  Intuit, I'm at your mercy.

Comment: Post the QBXML you are using to make the request.

Answer (score -1):

Submit a support request to Intuit. https://developer.intuit.com/help Please include verbose logs.